# jackson: catch exceptions for single items when deserializing a list

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapping

I have the following problem: There's a REST API that returns a JSON String that I want to map to List. MyObject has several fields, some of them int/double. Let's consider the API could be returning Strings instead of ints/doubles for one of those fields for SOME of the MyObjects, the rest is okay.

Now I want the mapper to still map this to a List while throwing out the faulty MyObjects. However, calling

```
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, MyObject.class));
```

will either succeed if all MyObjects are okay or fail completely when facing the first problem.

I was hoping to, kind of, find a spot where the mapper iterates over a list of JSON-MyObjects and mapping them to Java-MyObjects one by one. That way I'd be able to override that behavior and maybe surround it with a try-catch block and catch any exception that occurs while mapping a single MyObject. No luck so far, but maybe I'm just blind.

Any idea how to accomplish this with jackson is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using Jackson's custom deserializer:

Here is my MyObject target class. It has an annotation which associate with it a custom deserializer:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyObjectDeserializer.class)
public class MyObject
{
    public int num;
    public String str;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "{" + num + "," + str + "}";
    }
}
```

Here is the custom deserializer. it checks if the type of the "num" property is int typed:

```
public class MyObjectDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyObject>
{
    // read current MyObject json node
    JsonNode myObjectNode = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);// this will read 
    // read "num" property into JsonNode and check what subclass was created
    JsonNode numNode = myObjectNode.get("num");
    if (numNode instanceof IntNode) {  // test if value of num is int indeed
        MyObject o = new  MyObject();
        o.num = ((IntNode)numNode).intValue();  // read int value
        o.str = ((TextNode)myObjectNode.get("str")).asText();  // this is how to read string typed property
        return o;
    } else {
        return null;  // or any default/error value
    }
}
```

now assuming the following input, notice the 2nd object has a string typed "num" property:

```
[{"num":1,"str":"n1"}, {"num":"s","str":"n2"}, {"num":3,"str":"n3"}]
```

without the custom deserializer, you would get an exception. and with it you get the output:

```
[{1,n1}, null, {3,n3}]
```